# Number of ways of selecting equal number of rows and columns from a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, terminology

What is the total number of ways of selecting equal number of rows and columns from an $n\times m$ matrix?

If we write it mathematically it comes out to be
$$\binom{m}{0}\binom{n}{0} + \binom{m}{1}\binom{n}{1} + \binom{m}{2}\binom{m}{2} + \ldots + \binom{m}{m}\binom{n}{m} \qquad{\text{for}}~m \leq n$$

But, I am facing difficulty in reducing this expression.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the binomial theorem, we can write down
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{p=0}^n{n\choose p}x^p,$$

$$(1+\frac{1}{x})^m=\sum_{q=0}^m{m\choose q}x^{-q}.$$

Multiplying the two series, we obtain
$$(1+x)^n(1+\frac{1}{x})^m=\sum_{p=0}^n\sum_{q=0}^m{n\choose p}{m\choose q}x^{p-q}.$$

The $x^0$ term of the above expansion is what we want. Notice that

$$(1+x)^n(1+\frac{1}{x})^m=\frac{(1+x)^{n+m}}{x^m}.$$

So we want the $x^m$ term of $(1+x)^{n+m}$, which is ${n+m\choose m}x^m$. Therefore

$$\sum_{q=0}^m{n\choose q}{m\choose q}={n+m\choose m},\quad m\leq n.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i was looking for.